# The beginners guide to React Native and Firebase, Example for modification?

Tags: firebase, react-native

The beginners guide to React Native and Firebase

July 14, 2016

David East
Developer Advocate

Hello, my name is Shoji Itagaki.
I tried to make this example to work on event management.
Originally example is for grocery using firebase database.
My intension was to build event management tool like Facebook’s F8app.

Screen1 is for Registration management of event, event is selected and Registration.
Screen 2 is for Receptionist management,

Screen 2 is blank,
it seem to be not working on transfer from screen 1 to Screen2

```
    DB’s class is as follows.
    Event class(Event, day, start time , end time, etc)
    Registration class(User, Event etc)
```

```
Screen 1 Outline of Firebase database management.
this.itemsRef = this.getRef().child('items’);　For Event Class reference pointer
this.userRef = this.getRef().child('user’);　　For User Registration  Class

getRef() {return firebaseApp.database().ref();}
```

var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;　　get user account
      　   this.setState({user: user});　                for render

```
render section
     mail=this.state.user.email;
     console.log('mail = '  + mail);
     mail=mail.substring(0,mail.indexOf("@"));
     console.log('after modify mail = ' + mail);
    this.userRef = firebaseApp.database().ref('user/' + mail);
    this.userRef.push(new User(event,password,user);
This screen was OK and DB was created as follows.
rera06x
*
      -KXih12q_2XE24UQ6S7p
    *
event:
      *
password:
*
user
    *
_key:
    *
```

title:
    *
    -KXih_ZHuf12YujhC0Bl
    *
    event
        *
    _key:
        *
    title:
    *
    password
        *
    _key:
        *
    title:
    *
    user
        *
    _key:
        *
    title:
    *
    -KXikRGmj9LTENY3yBDr
    *
    event
        *
    _key:
        *
     title:
    *
    password
        *
    _key:
        *
    title:
    *
    user
        *
    _key:
        *
    title:

```
Screen ２  for Receptionist  and Firebase database process's outline
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;　 same as screen 1, to get     user account

componentDidMount() {
this.listenForItems(this.userRef);

  this.userRef = firebaseApp.database().ref('user/' + mail);

listenForItems(userRef) {　　　　　　　In this section, The Registration    list was get,
userRef.on('value', (snap) => {
```

---

`// get children as an array
  var user = [];
  snap.forEach((child) => {
    user.push({
      event: child.val().event,
      _key: child.key
    });
  });

  this.setState({
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(user)
  });
});
}

render() {
return (
<ListView
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={this._renderItem.bind(this)}
      enableEmptySections={true}
      style={styles.listview}/>
abridgment

_renderItem(user) {
const onPress = () => {
  Alert.alert(
    'Registration',
    null,
    [
      {text: 'Registration', onPress: (user) =>　uketukeExec },
      {text: 'Cancel', onPress: (user) => console.log('Cancelled')}
    ]
  );
};
return (
  <ListItem1 item={user} onPress={onPress} />　★★★★★★★★★★★
);
  }
}

class ListItem1 extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.onPress}>
        <View style={styles.li}>
         <Text style={styles.liText}>{this.props.item.event}</Text>　

This process does not work
      </View>
  </TouchableHighlight>
abridgement`

Any comment will be appreciated.
Shoji

Comment: Error is as follows.Object are not valid as a React child(found:object with key{_key,title}). if you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render of text.

Comment: My Error is as floows.            Object are not valid as a React child(found:object with key{_key,title}). if you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render of text.

Comment: I want render 1 items path is "rera06x/event/title". Next error shows render of collectionas child is wrong.Original application was for only grosary 1 item. so, adding some items was cause of this error?

Comment: I found the reason about error.

Comment: I found the reason of this error. Firebase RealtimeDatabase Push operation adds _key item illegally. I'm investigating why different action occurred.

Answer (score 0):

At last, after deeply debugging, I found the BUG.
The cause of the error was my poor program.
My intension was achieved with happy.

Anyway,  The beginners guide to React Native and Firebase 
is the best article in this area, especially like me new to Firebase.

Thanks
Shoji